# IQKeyboardManagerSwift 3.3.7 with ios 7

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

[IQKeyboardManagerSwift](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) says "[3.3.7 is the last iOS 7 supported version](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager#installation)".

In my podfile I have:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
...
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '3.3.7'
```

but when I run `pod install` I get:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `IQKeyboardManagerSwift (= 3.3.7)` required by `Podfile`
Specs satisfying the `IQKeyboardManagerSwift (= 3.3.7)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

The documentation says 3.3.7 works with 7, but in my code that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should check Deployment Target.

Comment: My app deployment target is set to 7.0. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: IQKeyboardManagerSwift:-
Minimum iOS Target: iOS 8.0 try with target 8.0.

Comment: For more info you can check http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/4.0.2/